# "cryptodev_digest_update: illegal inputs" error when trying to cipher a number with rsa public key using PKCS1_OAEP at an ARM board

Tags: c++, arm, public-key-encryption, poco-libraries

I've created a c++ app that runs on a arm7l board with linux v3.10.17-rt12+yocto. At some point I need to cipher a rsa public key. The public key I'm using is created using openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private_rsa.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

For that case I have used poco library. The code I've created is the following:

```
Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory &factory = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory();
Poco::Crypto::Cipher* pCipher = factory.createCipher(Poco::Crypto::RSAKey("public.pem"), RSA_PADDING_PKCS1_OAEP);
Poco::Crypto::CryptoTransform *pEncryptor = NULL;
pEncryptor = pCipher->createEncryptor();
std::stringstream memstream;
Poco::Crypto::CryptoOutputStream encryptor(memstream, pEncryptor);
std::string number = "123456789";
encryptor << number;
encryptor.close();
```

After the encryptor.close() command I get the following error message :

```
cryptodev_digest_update: illegal inputs
```

However when I try the RSA_PADDING_PKCS1 or even RSA_PADDING_NONE the code works correct. I don't want to remove kernel cryptodev for the time being.

The openssl version is :

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1s
```

The openssl engines are:

```
(cryptodev) cryptodev engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
```

While the supported openssl commands are:

```
Standard commands
asn1parse         ca                ciphers           cms               
crl               crl2pkcs7         dgst              dh                
dhparam           dsa               dsaparam          ec                
ecparam           enc               engine            errstr            
gendh             gendsa            genpkey           genrsa            
nseq              ocsp              passwd            pkcs12            
pkcs7             pkcs8             pkey              pkeyparam         
pkeyutl           prime             rand              req               
rsa               rsautl            s_client          s_server          
s_time            sess_id           smime             speed             
spkac             srp               ts                verify            
version           x509              

Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
md4               md5               mdc2              rmd160            
sha               sha1              

Cipher commands (see the `enc' command for more details)
aes-128-cbc       aes-128-ecb       aes-192-cbc       aes-192-ecb       
aes-256-cbc       aes-256-ecb       base64            bf                
bf-cbc            bf-cfb            bf-ecb            bf-ofb            
camellia-128-cbc  camellia-128-ecb  camellia-192-cbc  camellia-192-ecb  
camellia-256-cbc  camellia-256-ecb  cast              cast-cbc          
cast5-cbc         cast5-cfb         cast5-ecb         cast5-ofb         
des               des-cbc           des-cfb           des-ecb           
des-ede           des-ede-cbc       des-ede-cfb       des-ede-ofb       
des-ede3          des-ede3-cbc      des-ede3-cfb      des-ede3-ofb      
des-ofb           des3              desx              idea              
idea-cbc          idea-cfb          idea-ecb          idea-ofb          
rc2               rc2-40-cbc        rc2-64-cbc        rc2-cbc           
rc2-cfb           rc2-ecb           rc2-ofb           rc4               
rc4-40            seed              seed-cbc          seed-cfb          
seed-ecb          seed-ofb
```

Has anyone come across a similar problem? Is there a correlation between the padding algorithm and cryptodev because I haven't find anything relevant ?